Custom PHP settings - PHP-FPM
I am setting up a server, and I was wondering where to modify global PHP settings. I see there is a dir /etc/php/8.3/fpm/ with several files and folders inside.
I am trying to do this because I need to change PHP options like memory_limit, upload_max_filesize and date.timezone.
Nginx 1.26.2 / PHP 8.3.11

Please add some details. What version of Ubuntu are you using? Why are you trying to do this?

I updated the post with application versions. I am trying to do this because I need to update PHP options like memory_limit, upload_max_filesize and date.timezone. It seems pretty usual.

The settings you are looking for are in /etc/php/8.3/fpm/php.ini.
Once you update the file, don't forget to restart the php-fpm service with:
sudo service php8.3-fpm restart

